Embed ARC Relationship Graphs in LWCs? Is it possible?
The ARC Relationship Graph can show a very nice visual for the relationship of a household to its contacts. I am wondering if there is any way this can be embedded into an LWC instead of having to attempt to reinvent the wheel here when it is right there... But so far I haven't seen anything that seems to expose it for use.

Try posting to the Nonprofit Cloud Trailblazer group, but most likely you'll need to open a case with SF to get an answer.
